# Usage of 'to' in a sentence

Tags: prepositions, sentence

Are these *to*s in right places so that the sentence is meaningful? The sentence talks about some people we need to persuade to live our life peacefully.

> And yes, look we have some judges to persuade to too, to live life peacefully ahead.

Comment: You may need to clarify/edit the sentence so that we understand your question.

Comment: I think you have two to's correct, but one to too many.

Comment: Are these 'to's in right places so that the sentence is meaningful? And the sentence talks about some people we need to persuade to live our life peacefully.

Comment: I think you need to replace *persuade* with *talk to*, to achieve the effect you want.

Comment: You just persuade someone, you don't _persuade to_. You would only use _to_ if it were followed by an infinitive, e.g. _persuade someone to go home_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[your guy is in court, I assume]

Perhaps:

*To get rid of any troubles and live peacefully forever thereafter, we
 might have to first **work some convincing/persuading on** these judges/jurors.*

*To get rid of any troubles and live peacefully forever thereafter, we
 might have to first **make some convincing/persuading  work  on** these judges/jurors.*

Comment: Your answer was helpful, but I loved the repetition of those 'tos' in the sentence ,while reading it. And so I was asking if the sentence was grammatically correct.